# Category defined by a finite commutative diagram

Tags: category-theory, terminology

What is the name for a category defined by a finite commutative diagram?

Maybe category "induced" by a commutative diagram? or category "defined" by a commutative diagram?

Also, what is the exact definition of this intuitively clean concept?

Answer (score 3):

It is usually called the **free category** on (over) the diagram, but the term '*induced by*' is also clear.

We can formalize *abstract diagrams* as directed graphs (i.e. quivers) with a set of *commutativity conditions*, which are just pairs of parallel paths.

Then we have the usual free-forgetful adjunction between these abstract diagrams and categories.